# JS Object with an asynchronously set property

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, jquery, publish-subscribe

I set Person.name using an async function (think ajax call). Unfortunately, I'd still like to user other functions from the object without having to place them in a callback.

How can I use functions that depend on an object's asynchronously set property?

Code to execute:

```
var user = new Person();
user.setName(); // This is async.
var is_jennifer = user.isItJennifer(); // Oh no! the user's name may not be defined yet!
...
...
var is_tom = user.isItTom(); // Much later in the code I need the async property again. I don't want to cram all of this into a callback whenever I setName.
```

Object with a method `setName()` that is asynchronous.

```
function Person() {
  // Properties
  this.name = null;

  this.setName = function() {
    this.name = NameModelThing.getName(); // Oh no! getName returns a result asynchronously.
  }

  this.isItJennifer = function() {
    return (this.name == 'Jennifer') ? true : false;
  }

  this.isItTom = function() {
    return (this.name == 'Tom') ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for are "promises" and "defered objects"...

Comment: How is `NameModelThing.getName()` implemented?

Comment: does that mean you are opposed to putting the name in a detached node with an onchange event set for the remaining functions ... otherwise you can use setInterval to poll for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jquery for your ajax requests, you can make the request not asynchronous by passing in async: false as an option.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As an alternative, you could use a pattern where you have some sort of initialization for your Person object when you load the page, and use a callback from there:

```
var user = new Person();
user.fetch({
  success: function() {
  // code when user ready here.
  }
});
```